# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python

I need to make a function that updates tuples in a list of tuples. The tuples contain transactions, which are characterised by ammount, day, and type. I made this function that should completely replace a tuple with a new one, but  when I try to print the updated list of tuples I get the error:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The code:

```
def addtransaction(transactions, ammount, day, type): 
    newtransactions = {
        "Ammount": ammount,
        "Day": day,
        "Type": type
        }
   transactions.append(newtransaction)

def show_addtransaction(transactions):
     Ammount = float(input("Ammount: "))
     Day = input("Day: ")
     Type = input("Type: ")
    addtransaction(transactions, ammount, day, type)

def show_all_transaction(transactions):
    print()
    for i, transaction in enumerate(transactions):
        print("{0}. Transaction with the ammount of {1} on day {2} of type:     {3}".format(
            i + 1,
            transaction['Ammount'], ; Here is where the error occurs.
            transaction['Day'],
            transaction['Type']))

def update_transaction(transactions): ; "transactions" is the list of tuples
    x = input("Pick a transaction by index:") 
    a = float(input("Choose a new ammount:"))
    b = input("Choose a new day:")
    c = input("Choose a new type:")
    i = x
    transactions[int(i)] = (a, b, c)

addtransaction(transactions, 1, 2, service)
show_all_transaction(transactions)
update_transaction(transactions)
show_all_transaction(transactions)
```

Comment: This code will not produce the error you stated. Please provide the actual code and the appropriate traceback error.

Comment: `transactions[int(i)] = (a, 'b', 'c')` should be `transactions[int(i)] = (a, b, c)`. Also what's the point of `i=0` if you are asking `x = input("Pick a transaction by index:")`?

Comment: From what little code you have provided, it looks like you might need to convert `x` to an `int`. You certainly do not need to convert the `int` `0` to an `int`...

Comment: Also, do you really want to be updating at index 0 every time or should it say `transactions[int(x)]` ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention, the error appears when I try to print the newly created tuple.

Comment: How do you actually call `update_transaction`? And the given exception doesn't really make sense. You cannot reassign an element in the tuple (so `transactions` cannot be the tuple). Then please show us where the error actually appears.

Comment: 'transactions" is the list of tuples, does calling print(transactions[1]) print the first tuple in the list?

Comment: Oh, I just saw that I did a little mistake, I'm sorry, it should be "i = x" instead of "i = 0"

Comment: No it'll print the second entry. Tuples (and list and strings) start at index 0, so it should be `transactions[0]`. But that shouldn't be the cause of the exception.

Comment: You need to show the code where the error actually occurs because currently there isn't really much more to say than the exception already tells you.

Comment: I edited the code and added the part where the error occurs

Comment: Don't comment with `;` use `#`

Comment: `transactions` is undefined.

Comment: Your indentations seem of. Also in `show_addtransaction` you define uppercase variables (like `Day`) but use them lowercase (like `day`). In Python those are different, only use only one of them but not both. And a minor thing I think it is [amount](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/amount) with only one “m”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tuple is basically only a `list`, with the difference that in a `tuple` you cannot overwrite a value in it without creating a new `tuple`.

This means you can only access each value by an index starting at 0, like `transactions[0][0]`.

But as it appears you should actually use a `dict` in the first place. So you need to rewrite `update_transaction` to actually create a `dict` similar to how `addtransaction` works. But instead of adding the new transaction to the end you just need to overwrite the transaction at the given index.

This is what `update_transaction` already does, but it overwrites it with a tuple and not a `dict`. And when you print it out, it cannot handle that and causes this error.

**Original answer** (Before I knew the other functions)

If you want to use strings as indexes you need to use a `dict`. Alternatively you can use [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) which are like tuples but it also has an attribute for each value with the name you defined before. So in your case it would be something like:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Transaction = namedtuple("Transaction", "amount day type")
```

The names given by the string used to create `Transaction` and separated by spaces or commas (or both). You can create transactions by simply calling that new object. And accessing either by index or name.

```
new_transaction = Transaction(the_amount, the_day, the_type)
print(new_transaction[0])
print(new_transaction.amount)
```

Please note that doing `new_transaction["amount"]` will still not work.

Comment: I added two functions which add a new transaction, they were written by my professor so I do not know very well their functionality, but I know they allow me to use transaction("Day") or such

Comment: Okay this makes more sense. I edited the answer to reflect that. If you don't understand the `namedtuple` stuff it is fine and you should be able to fix it without it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a generic answer, I'll just mention it if someone bumps into the same problem.

As stated before, tuples are addressed by integer e.g. `my_tuple[int]` or     slice `my_tuple[int1:int2]`.

I ran into trouble when I ported code from Python2 to Python3. The original code used somthing like  `my_tuple[int1/int2]`, this worked in Python2 since division  int/int results in int.
in  Python3 int/int results in a floating point number.
I had to fix the code to `my_tuple[int1//int2]` to get the python2 behavior.